# netbeans format array align

Tags: netbeans, code-formatting

i have a question about the netbeans formatting wich i use to format my code to the company code conventions here.

But i have a problem formatting the closing parentheses from an arrays.

current formatting:

```
$array = array(
    'item1-moretext' => 1 ,
    'itm2'           => 2 ,
    'itm3-moretext'  => 3
                ) ;
```

and this is how i want it to be formatted:

```
$array = array(
    'item1-moretext' => 1 ,
    'itm2'           => 2 ,
    'itm3-moretext'  => 3
) ;
```

As far as i know i have tried every possible combination.

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans PHP spaces in array declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853565/netbeans-php-spaces-in-array-declaration)