# Netbeans PHP spaces in array declaration

Tags: php, netbeans, formatting

Simple question, I have array:

```
array(
  'aaa' => 1,
  'bbbbbbbb' => 2,
  'ccccc' => 3,
  'dd' => 4
);
```

and I want format code to:

```
array(
  'aaa'       => 1,
  'bbbbbbbb'  => 2,
  'ccccc'     => 3,
  'dd'        => 4
);
```

Is there a Formatting option to do this, because I don't see anything like this?

PS. Sorry for my English.

Comment: It's a php array, I don't know why I write this like noob, sorry.

Comment: replace = with => and then press alt+shif+f to reformat the code

Comment: I have => in code, alt+shift+f not help me, because this reformatting code to one space before and after =>

Comment: i think https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/formatting_group_multiline_alignment_added this will help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP code into NetBeans 7.1 In Alignment category there are new properties for Group Multiline Alignment - Assignment and Array Initializer.

[image]

On the left site -  Assignment property is off and on the right site the property is on. As you can see, when the property is set on, then the assignment char '=' is placed after the longest identifier in a group. The group is defined as a number of lines that contains the same type of assignments. End of a group can be empty line, line where is only a comment, different expression, end of a block. This formatting options works for variable assignment, field initialization and constants.

The second new property is for Array Initializer.

Both properties are switched off by default. Just turn it on and you are done.

Comment: Although, this formats mid-line indentation with `tabs`, not with `spaces`. In this case, spaces should be used, because of different `tab` lengths. But I did not found is this configurable.

Comment: Yes. I also want to find this!

Answer (score 5):

I am working on NETBEAN for so long, The Best practise is alt+shift+F

Comment: yes formating will be done by alt+shift+F but to align array you need to enable it from formatting tab